# how to give margin to cursor in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

could you please tell me how to give margin to cursor position it just touch the start point of rectangle .?

[image]

here is my code

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/background_textfield"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textColor="#000000" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item  ><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="2dp" />

                <solid android:color="#f7fbfc" />
            </shape></item>

    </layer-list></item>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Indirect Solution:  wrap the TextView in a ViewGroup and apply  android:layout_marginLeft to the textView.   Put whatever background you want as the background of the viewgroup and leave the textview transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add

```
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
```

Comment: where i need to write...!!

Comment: indide  <AutoCompleteTextView/> tag

Comment: please look out this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686451/why-space-occur-in-between-image-view-and-top-in-android